# sequelize-typescript: @PrimaryKey decorator not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to use a string as the primary key for one of my tables instead of `id`, but on `create` Sequelize always tries to set a default `id`.

```
import { 
  Model,
  DataType,
  Table,
  Column,
  PrimaryKey,
  ForeignKey,
  HasOne,
  BelongsTo
} from "sequelize-typescript";
import { sequelize } from "../loaders/database";
import { Enterprise } from "./enterprise";
import { Welfare } from "./welfare";
import { Meal } from "./meal";
import { Qualification } from "./qualification";

@Table
export class Recruit extends Model {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column({
    type: DataType.STRING(30),
    field: "recruit_id"
  })
  recruitId!: string;

  @Column(DataType.CHAR(10))
  reception!: string;

  @Column(DataType.CHAR(10))
  deadline!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.TINYINT,
    field: 'recruit_plan'
  })
  recruitPlan!: boolean;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.CHAR(5),
    field: 'start_time'
  })
  startTime!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.CHAR(5),
    field: 'end_time'
  })
  endTime!: string;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  salary!: number;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  period!: number;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.TINYINT,
    defaultValue: false
  })
  expired!: boolean;

  @Column(DataType.INTEGER)
  personnel!: number;
  
  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  detail!: string;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.TINYINT,
    defaultValue: false
  })
  writing!: boolean;

  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    defaultValue: 1
  })
  page!: number;

  @ForeignKey(() => Enterprise)
  @Column({
    type: DataType.CHAR(12),
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'ent_no'
  })
  entNo!: string;

  @HasOne(() => Welfare, "recruit_id")
  welfare!: Welfare;

  @HasOne(() => Meal, "recruit_id")
  meal!: Meal;

  @HasOne(() => Qualification, "recruit_id")
  qualification!: Qualification;

  @BelongsTo(() => Enterprise, "ent_no")
  enterprise!: Enterprise;
}

Recruit.init({}, {
  sequelize,
  tableName: "recruit",
  modelName: "recruit"
});
```

After initalizing the project, I defined Recruit Model with `sequelize-typescript`.

```
public async getRecruitInfoById(recruitId: string) {
    return await Recruit.findOne({
      attributes: [
        'ent_no',
        'deadline',
        ['detail', 'workContent'],
        'salary',
        'period',
        'start_time',
        'end_time',
        'personnel',
        'reception'
      ],
      where: {
        recruitId
      },
      include: [
        {
          model: Enterprise,
          required: true,
          attributes: ['name', 'phone']
        }
      ]
    });
```

And, execute this function.

I expect the record to get info.

But, Sequelize tries to set primary key a default `id`, which isn't present in the table.

```
2021-03-06 13:23:51 error: undefined: Unknown column 'recruit.id' in 'field list'
    at new BelongsTo (C:\Users\user\Desktop\프로젝트\jobITs\jobITs_v2_Backend_Red\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\belongs-to.js:59:13)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\프로젝트\jobITs\jobITs_v2_Backend_Red\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:105:25)
    at Function.Model.<computed> [as belongsTo] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\프로젝트\jobITs\jobITs_v2_Backend_Red\node_modules\sequelize-typescript\dist\model\model\model.js:118:28) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\프로젝트\jobITs\jobITs_v2_Backend_Red\src\entities\index.ts:54:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\user\Desktop\프로젝트\jobITs\jobITs_v2_Backend_Red\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1056:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\프로젝트\jobITs\jobITs_v2_Backend_Red\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1059:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
```